# Html inside script tags - width and height not recognized

Tags: javascript, html, width

I'm using a script to display pictures from Instagram on my website. The script itself works fine but I'm having an issue with the html code.

Inside the script, there's some html code so that when a user clicks on one of the Instagram pictures, there's a link to that Instagram page which should open in a new pop-up window. I want that pop-up window to have a width and height of 500 pixels.

With the code below each link is opened in a new tab, not in a new pop-up window. I suppose the problem is caused by the html tags. I thought I should escape the inner tags but clearly that's not the solution.

What am I missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var userFeed = new Instafeed1({
            get: 'user',
            userId: 'my_user_id',
            accessToken:'my_access_token',
            limit:'50',
            resolution:'low_resolution',
            template: '<div class="instafeed"><div class="instafeed-image"><a href="{{link}}" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, \'width=500, height=500\')" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a><div class="instafeed-text"><a href="{{link}}" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, \'width=500, height=500\')" target="_blank"> {{likes}} {{comments}}</a></div></div></div>'
        });
        userFeed.run();
    </script>
    <div id="instafeed1"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show in image?

Comment: Make sure to disable any popup blockers, which often force new windows into tabs. Of course this only helps for your testing. Won't help on any client machines that might have popups disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) takes 3 arguments:

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures]);
```

Where `strUrl` is the url to be loaded in the newly opened window,
`strWindowName` is a string name for the new window and `strWindowFeatures` is an optional parameter listing the features of the new window as a string.

You are not supplying an argument for the window name, thus making your window features the name of the new window instead of window features.

To solve your problem simply add an argument to your call to `window.open()`:

```
template: '<div class="instafeed"><div class="instafeed-image"><a href="{{link}}" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, \'COOL_WINDOW_NAME\',\'width=500, height=500\')" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a><div class="instafeed-text"><a href="{{link}}" onclick="return !window.open(this.href, \'COOL_WINDOW_NAME\', \'width=500, height=500\')" target="_blank"> {{likes}} {{comments}}</a></div></div></div>'
```